# Update an array using Jongo

Tags: mongodb, jackson, jongo

I have a mongodb collection of the form

```
{
  "_id":"id",
  "userEmail":"userEmailFromCustomerCollection",
  "customerFavs":[
    "www.xyz.com",
    "www.xyz.com",
    "www.xyz.com"

    ]
}
```

I need to add an element to the customers favs array using Jongo , I am using the following code snippet to do so .

```
String query = "{userEmail:'"+emailId+"'}";
    customerFavCollection.update(query).with("{$addToSet:{customerFavs:#}}", favUrl);
```

My problem , is that I need to upsert the document if the document does not 
exist already , how can I do so using Jongo, I know an easier option would be to retrieve the document by Id and if it does not exist then insert the document using save() , but I am trying to avoid the extra retrieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `upsert()` on the query.

```
customerFavCollection.update("userEmail:#", emailId)
                     .with("{$addToSet:{customerFavs:#}}", favUrl)
                     .upsert();
```